# Sum and average after datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem trying to make a sum after the date within an hour and the average from column no. 2 and also after the date within an hour. I tried something like this, but there are errors.

```
df[6] = df.groupby(df[5].dt.hour).sum() 
df
```

I know how to do the whole column, but I do not know how the average is in an hour. He would like to get such an effect:

```
     2   3   4   5                         Sum        Average
0   29  12  296 2017-01-01 01:00:07.500     4           47,7
1   29  12  296 2017-01-01 01:00:07.500     4           47,7
2   66  5   646 2017-01-01 01:00:31.410     4           47,7  
3   66  5   646 2017-01-01 01:00:31.410     4           47,7  
4   63  5   596 2017-01-01 02:00:32.670     2            63
5   63  5   596 2017-01-01 02:00:32.670     2            63
6   43  8   655 2017-01-01 03:00:36.720     2            43 
7   43  8   655 2017-01-01 03:00:36.720     2            43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 df['Avg'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=5, freq='H'))[2].transform('mean')
```

Comment: @young_programmer Change `'mean'` to `'sum'`

Comment: ok @liliscent, only I want the sum of records at a given hour. And as you say it sums up the values from Column 2

Comment: @young_programmer I don't understand what you mean by "sum". If you want exactly the result in your sample data, you can use `'count'`. But this is not called a "sum", it's a "count".